# reduce() operation on stream seems to be modifying the source of data (list) Stream API Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, pass-by-reference, reduce

I have a simple POJO called Transaction with three private properties String type,double amount and String id.
In main class,I created few instances of Transaction calling the constructor as written below -

```
List<Transaction> transList = Arrays.asList(new Transaction(Transaction.TRANSACTION_TYPE_GROCERY,45.50,"2a"),
                                            new Transaction(Transaction.TRANSACTION_TYPE_GROCERY,50.0,"1a"),
                                            new Transaction(Transaction.TRANSACTION_TYPE_GROCERY,15.00,"3a"),
                                            new Transaction(Transaction.TRANSACTION_TYPE_GROCERY,27.43,"4a"),
                                            new Transaction(Transaction.TRANSACTION_TYPE_CLOTHING,145.0,"5a"),
                                            new Transaction(Transaction.TRANSACTION_TYPE_CLOTHING,105.0,"6a"));
```

Now I have called below operation on this listusing below code -

```
Optional<Transaction> totalA = transList.stream()
.filter(x->x.getType()==Transaction.TRANSACTION_TYPE_GROCERY)
.reduce((a,b) -> {Transaction z = b;                                                                             
                  z.setAmount(a.getAmount()+b.getAmount());
                  return z;});
```

Here I have tried to perform reduction operation by keeping Transaction as the lowest unit and calculate the sum of all transaction amounts and set it inside a new Transaction z. All this gets stored finally as Optional.
After this, if I try to carry out any other operation on the transList data source,I get incorrect results as the state of transList gets disrupted.

```
List<String> transactionIds = transList.stream()
                                                .filter(x -> x.getAmount()>50.00)
                                                .map(Transaction::getId)
                                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(transactionIds);
```

I have done the Optional containing Double item and double return value implementations successfully for this list using reduce().
All I want to know is what is so wrong with the Optional that it ends up modifying the source of data itself, which should not happen as Stream is functional.

Comment: The result of the System.out.println(transactionIds); should be [5a, 6a]. However, above  code upon execution returns [1a, 3a, 4a, 5a, 6a].

Comment: Do not comment your question. *Edit* it.

Comment: This looks suspicious - `Transaction z = b; z.setAmount(a.getAmount()+b.getAmount());` Copying b into z does not create a copy of the object, so you're effectively modifying b.

Comment: On one hand, `reduce` in your first stream pipeline consists of a flaw, while you return a new `Transaction` with `amount` added and since the `type` is same for them anyway(reason: filter), you don't consider the `id` attribute in your operation. That's what would cause you to not persist all different `id`s as well. On the other hand modifying the existing object actually would bring this up instantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lambda:

```
(a,b) -> {Transaction z = b;                                                                             
                  z.setAmount(a.getAmount()+b.getAmount());
                  return z;}
```

Is modifying the `b` parameter. Keep in mind that an assignement does **not** copy an object so `Transaction z = b` is just giving an alias to the object pointed to by `b`.

You should probably use the `reduce` overload that allows to specify the identity and combiner, os just create a copy of the object.

Comment: Thank you. My query has been answered by all three of you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Transaction z = b;// doesn't create a new object.  
                                                    z.setAmount(a.getAmount()+b.getAmount()); //you actually set a amout to `b` object

return z; // and here you returm `b` object
```

Comment: Thank you. All three answers so far are correct explanations.

Answer (score 0):

It is everything ok with the Optional. Your object is a reference data type.
Here you copied the reference of your object `Transaction z = b;`. It doesn't create a new one. Now both variables point at the same `Transaction`. And no matter what you modify `z` or `b` it ends up modifying the source data

This might be useful https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/09/difference-between-primitive-and-reference-variable-java.html

Comment: Thank you. All three answers so far have explained my query correctly.